# App closing unexpectedly after a long period of time

Tags: android, android-webview

The app I have produced does some basic operations, including downloading some files from a server and then displaying them in a WebView.

The app footprint is pretty small and it runs nicely, for a while.

Ideally the app needs to run 24/7 but after a few test runs, the app is being killed.

In some instances, only the WebView activity is killed, and the app display my login screen (the Main activity)

I have watched the heap info in Eclipse and it looks stable, with GC kicking in and the usage % staying about 85%.

I do have a Runnable set to refresh the webview activity every 15 minutes, but this will be replaced with a background service. This current timer does not seem to affect the apps performance, with the app running smoothly for a couple of hours (the time i watched it run, it was then left alone over night, only to have quit by the time i got back to it in the morning)

If there any way to find out exactly what Android is doing to my app, why it either closes fully or quits back to the main activity?

(Also, I need a way to "adb logcat" over wifi, what's the quickest way to achieve this?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really stop your app getting killed by the OS. Android is designed in such a way to manage  apps that are not being actively used.

In your case, if you are planning to do something in the background, a background service is the ideal place to achieve that. You can never ensure that you app remains active all the time.

Comment: I have managed to read a Heap dump using Eclipse MAT and I am getting a suspected leak: The class "android.content.res.Resources", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 6,538,440 (60.93%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "<system class loader>". Could this be caused by the webview loading in my html file (which contains images)? How can I stop this?